# Conditional naming for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataset;

```
>>> all_transcripts

ID  Type    Name
1   Guest   Hugo
1   Guest   Hugo   
1   Boss    Boss
1   Boss    Boss
2   Boss    Boss
2   Guest   Calvin
2   Guest   Calvin             
3   Guest   Klein
3   Boss    Boss
```

Now, I want to create a column called `nameGuest` that contains the name of the guest per ID on every row. Thus, my desired output looks as follows:

```
>>> all_transcripts

ID  Type    Name     nameGuest
1   Guest   Hugo     Hugo
1   Guest   Hugo     Hugo   
1   Boss    Boss     Hugo
1   Boss    Boss     Hugo
2   Boss    Boss     Calvin
2   Guest   Calvin   Calvin
2   Guest   Calvin   Calvin    
3   Guest   Klein    Klein
3   Boss    Boss     Klein
```

How can I do this?

Comment: and also on non-guest rows, where `Type != 'Guest'`, you want us to group by `ID`, so that `nameGuest` is filled-in from `Name` column for the `Type == 'Guest'` rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by helper `Series` created by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for get first value of `Guest` per group:

```
s = df[df['Type'] == 'Guest'].drop_duplicates('ID').set_index('ID')['Name']
df['nameGuest'] = df['ID'].map(s)
print (df)
   ID   Type    Name nameGuest
0   1  Guest    Hugo      Hugo
1   1  Guest    Hugo      Hugo
2   1   Boss    Boss      Hugo
3   1   Boss    Boss      Hugo
4   2   Boss    Boss    Calvin
5   2  Guest  Calvin    Calvin
6   2  Guest  Calvin    Calvin
7   3  Guest   Klein     Klein
8   3   Boss    Boss     Klein
```

Answer (score 1):

## `Groupby.first`

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and before that filter on `Type=Guest` and select the [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) name while aggregating.

This will get us the names with corresponding `ID`. So we can map that back to our dataframe and create the new column:

---

```
names = df[df['Type'] == 'Guest'].groupby('ID')['Name'].first()

df['nameGuest'] = df['ID'].map(names)
```

---

```
print(df)
   ID   Type    Name nameGuest
0   1  Guest    Hugo      Hugo
1   1  Guest    Hugo      Hugo
2   1   Boss    Boss      Hugo
3   1   Boss    Boss      Hugo
4   2   Boss    Boss    Calvin
5   2  Guest  Calvin    Calvin
6   2  Guest  Calvin    Calvin
7   3  Guest   Klein     Klein
8   3   Boss    Boss     Klein
```

**Output of `names`**

```
print(names)
ID
1      Hugo
2    Calvin
3     Klein
Name: Name, dtype: object
```